# Failure to login using firebase auth on Android in release mode. DEBUG mode is OK. Code=10, message=10,mPendingCredential=null

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, release

I can run from android studio through a wire to my device and login using firebase auth to gmail successfully - with 2 gmail accounts I have.

When I push a release version to testers (mainly in India) they cannot login - error message is"

```
IdpResponse{mUser=null, mToken='null', mSecret='null', mIsNewUser='false', mException=f.f.a.a.e: Code: 10, message: 10: , mPendingCredential=null}
```

I am convinced it is related to the SHA Certificate fingerprints. I have 2 fingerprints in the firebase console - (SHA1 and SHA256 ) that match the gradle signing report in android studio. The release 'variant' is the same key as the debug - if this should be different how do I create a 'release' key (as opposed to a debug one) just for the release version and add it when I upload.

NOTES: I do use the screen - Generate Signed Bundle or APK - which points to the a store path created a long time ago by another developer. The code must be correct because debug login works. Some Stackoverflows mentions 3 keys - where is the 3rd from? Also NOTE Play App Signing
is enabled.

This is the last bug to fix before go live - so any help would be appreciated.

Firebase console:

[image]

Thanks
John Goodstadt

Answer (score 1):

This became solved by me doing 1 thing. In the Firebase Settings for the project select the 'Integrations' TAB. And click 'Manage', See image - bottom left box 'Google Play'. After this the login was fixed. Many other things were tried. Before this make sure that the latest google-services.json file is downloaded - it has a copy of secure keys.

Thanks
John Goodstadt

[image]